# Rails nested resource not rendering form on new

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, routes, form-for

@reckoner has_many @shift_requirements and in routes,

```
resources :reckoners do
  resources :shift_requirements
end
```

In a view under reckoner_controller.rb I have

```
<%= link_to 'create a shift', [:new, @reckoner, :shift_requirement]%>
```

... which fires the correct view containing a form helper. Then it throws the error -

```
undefined method `shift_requirements_path' for #<#<Class:0x007f908e00a458>:0x007f908e8a09c8>
```

How have I gone wrong?

shift_requirement.rb is -

```
class ShiftRequirement < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :reckoner
end
```

reckoner.rb is -

```
class Reckoner < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :shift_requirements
end
```

... and the view in the form is now

```
<%= form_for(@reckoner, @shift_requirement) do |f| %>
...
<%= f.submit %>
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume your form has:

```
<%= form_for(@shift_requirement) do |f| %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Because of your nested routes you want

```
<%= form_for([@reckoner, @shift_requirement]) do |f| %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Hi - thanks for answering. I've made the change, but it throws another error - `ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError in ShiftRequirements#new can't write unknown attribute `html'`

Comment: So `ShiftRequirement` is using ActiveModel?  Can you post that class in your question

Comment: In case someone else is getting `ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError` -  please make sure that parameters for `form_for` are passed as array `form_for([@a,@b])`, not as two separate parameters.